# Why is more memory allocated for a struct?

Tags: c, struct, sizeof, member

Consider the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct aStruct {
    int numA;
    int numB;
    int numC;
    int numD;
    int numE;
}A;

typedef struct bStruct {
    int numF;
    int numG;
    int numH;
    A* a;
}B;

int main(void) {
    printf("Size of struct A: %lu\n", sizeof (A));
    printf("Size of struct B: %lu\n", sizeof (B));

    return 0;
}
```

When I compile and run the code above on my 64-bit machine I get

```
Size of struct A: 20
Size of struct B: 24
```

I cannot understand why struct B comprises 24B. I would expect it to be 20B, 12B for the three integer members and 8B for the pointer. Initially I thought about memory alignment reasons, but according the the size of struct A, the system is able to allocate 20B.

Comment: Your pointer has to be aligned on an 8-byte boundary